# Strange Primary key issue with NULL record SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, null

I have a SQL Server 2016 database in which I noticed a strange issue or probably I'm missing something.

In table with Primary Key NOT NULL on a varchar column, NULL value is being allowed once if I enter the INSERT with value N''. Where as If I straight away use NULL for that column it throws an error cannot insert NULL.

Is N'' considered some valid character for Primary key column?

Here is the TSQL to reproduce the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testprmarykeynull]( 
[EmailId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
( 
[EmailId] ASC 
)
)


INSERT INTO testprmarykeynull VALUES('test@gmail.com');
INSERT INTO testprmarykeynull VALUES(N''); - Successfully insert this for the first time and the second time throws duplicate error. But from my understanding this should fail the first time itself since it's a NULL value. 
INSERT INTO testprmarykeynull VALUES(NULL); - Fails though even if I try with the first NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty string in MS SQL Server is **not** a `null` (unlike [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), e.g.) - see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/14255/0) for a demo.

Thus, it behaves like any other value - the first one you insert into a primary key column will be just fine, and the second one will fail since it violates the uniqueness of the column.

Comment: the `second one` you are referring to the `NULL` right ? then it should violates the primary key not null constraint

Comment: @Squirrel no - I meant the second time you attempt to insert an empty string (`''`). The first time you you succeed, and if you try to insert an empty string **again**, you will fail since it violates the uniqueness.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` and `N''` are definitely not the same in SQL Server - they never have been, and they never will be.

`N''` is an NVARCHAR value of length 0.
`NULL` is "the absence of a value".

There are many ways in which this difference becomes clear.
Examples:

```
SELECT LEN(N'')      -- returns 0
     , LEN(NULL)     -- returns NULL because almost any operation on NULL returns NULL

     , ISNULL(N'' , N'Hello')   -- returns N'' because N'' is a value
     , ISNULL(NULL, N'Hello')   -- returns N'Hello' because NULL is "not a value"
```